# Need help to auto enter date and time and calculate time elapsed since previous row's entry

Tags: ios, excel, vba, datetime, excel-formula

I need to form a spreadsheet or program where individual rows would have the date and time automatically entered when I type text as to a clinical event.

When I would enter text into the next row, I need it to enter that time, AND in another column give me the time elapsed since prior row's entry.

I have searched the internet for months, as I had a 'little' program that could do this on Windows many years ago. But now I need such to work on a Mac, iOS, and hopefully Windows as well. I can't find anything at any cost, but see a lot out there to track time for billing. I have Excel on all, and welcome suggestions. I am not a programmer, but a friend that just passed said he thought he could do with VB? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if vba is different on apple products but here’s one way it could be done (at least in windows).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Target.Worksheet

    If Target.Column >= 2 Then
        ws.Range("A" & Target.Row).Value = Now()
        If Target.Row - 1 <> 0 Then
            ws.Range("B" & Target.Row).Value = DateDiff("s", ws.Range("A" & Target.Row - 1).Value, ws.Range("A" & Target.Row).Value)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This will put a time stamp in Column A and time since previous rows entry in Column B (in seconds), whenever anything is entered in any other column on that row.  Note: There is limited error checking.

Comment: Code looks good, I understand this would execute as soon as the value of any cell in columns C or more to rigth ... change ...  but something needs to be changed elsewhere ... Can you please  explain what else need to do

Comment: This will put the time stamp into column A `ws.Range("A" & Target.Row).Value = Now()`, and if it's the second row or further down it will calculate the difference in date from the current row and previous row and put it in column B `ws.Range("B" & Target.Row).Value = DateDiff("s", ws.Range("A" & Target.Row - 1).Value, ws.Range("A" & Target.Row).Value)`.  I'm not sure what you mean, what else does it need to do?

Comment: A1 would be Date and Time displayed as mm/dd/yy - 2:10pm
B1 would be Text I enter that would then populate A1. (Event - such as drug given)
C1 (Text)
D1 (blank or 0)
BUT D2 would be Time since previous entry (row above) in hr;mm:ss. 
And thus I’d be able to “Time Stamp” the ‘intervention’ and see how long it had been since former row/entry.

Comment: You do not need to declare the worksheet here. `Worksheet_Change` is looking at the `Target` sheet by default. Those lines are redundant here